# swift regex for finding date in string

Tags: swift, regex, string

Im trying to find the occurence of date range formatted like this: "2415/2418" in a larger string.

When I use the following code, nothing is found, even though I can see the date is in the string.

```
let regex = "\\[0-9]{4}\\/\\[0-9]{4}"
if let range = myString.range(of:regex, options: .regularExpression)
```

Comment: Try `[0-9]{4}\\/[0-9]{4}`

Answer (score 1):

The character ranges must not be escaped and it's not required to escape the slash in this case.
 `[0-9]` can be replaced with `\\d`

It's either

```
let regex = "[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{4}"
```

or

```
let regex = "\\d{4}/\\d{4}"
```